# Is there a way to crossfade relatively positioned divs (with dynamic heights)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is fade div 1 out and fade div 2 in at the same time, over each other...

Both divs are relative and are vertically stacked - the content within those divs is also likely to change constantly so fixed margins, heights, etc. won't work...

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jwzwycdm/

I've added height: 0 but it completely kills the fade animations:

```
   div { height: 0px; 
         opacity: 0; 
         transition: opacity 0.5s; }

  .active { height: 100%;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: opacity 0.5s; }
```

This is the exact effect I'm trying to achieve - using absolute positioning does the trick but completely ruins any elements that may come below those two:

https://jsfiddle.net/jwzwycdm/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest the 2 DIVs in a parent DIV with `position:relative`. Then make the two child DIVs `position:absolute`. See code:

https://jsfiddle.net/jwzwycdm/5/

Comment: There are likely to be more elements below those two, though - won't the :absolute element affect the positioning of other things on the page?

Comment: @IgorMitic No, because its parent has position: relative.

Comment: The only thing that will happen is that the below content will jump up, because both DIVs don't share the same height.